# Find the Same day of Previous Year Given by Current Year Date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am working with SQL Server, The scenario is to find out the Same Day's Date of Previous Year as of Today's Day.

Suppose **2014-03-06** is Today Date and Day is **Thursday** I want to Find the Same day in Previous lies in the same week .which is **2013-03-07**

can any body help?
HERE is what i Have Written:

```
 DECLARE @DateFrom AS DATETIME
 DECLARE @DateTo AS DATETIME 


SET @DateFrom = '2014-01-01'
SET @DateTo = '2014-02-10'


DECLARE @Count AS INT

SET @Count = DATEDIFF(DAY, @DateFrom, @DateTo)


CREATE TABLE #current_year /*This Year*/
(
  [Date] DATETIME ,
  WeekNum INT,
  [Day] VARCHAR(20),
  Data INT
)
CREATE TABLE #last_year /*This Year -1*/
(
  [Date] DATETIME ,
  WeekNum INT,
  [Day] VARCHAR(20),
  Data INT
)
WHILE ( @Count > 0 ) 
        BEGIN
            INSERT  INTO #current_year
            VALUES  ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DateFrom, 101),                        
                      DATEPART(week,@DateFrom),
                      DATENAME(weekday, @DateFrom),@Count)          
            INSERT  INTO #last_year
            VALUES  ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @DateFrom), 101),                                                  
                      DATEPART(week,DATEADD(YEAR,1,@DateFrom)),
                      DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @DateFrom)),@Count)  
            SET @DateFrom = DATEADD(day, 1, @DateFrom)
            SET @Count = @Count - 1
        END      
        SELECT * from #current_year     
        SELECT * from #last_year   

        SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),#current_year.[Date],111) AS CYDate,
               --ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),#last_year.[Date],111) ,/*CONVERT(varchar(10),DateAdd(dd, 1, DATEADD(yy, -1, #current_year.Date)),111)*/) AS LYDate
               --CONVERT(varchar(10),#last_year.[Date],111) AS LYDate
               Coalesce(CONVERT(varchar(10),#last_year.[Date],111) ,DateAdd(dd, 1, DATEADD(yy, -1, #current_year.Date))) AS LYDate,
               #current_year.Data AS CD,
               #last_year.Data AS LD
               FROM #current_year                            
               --LEFT JOIN #last_year ON #last_year.WeekNum = #current_year.WeekNum
   --                                 AND #last_year.[Day] = #current_year.[Day]
                                    Left JOIN #last_year ON #last_year.WeekNum =  DatePart(wk, GETDATE())



DROP TABLE #current_year
DROP TABLE #last_year
```

Here is the Output: [image]

Here is the output after adding your solution, now in left join it excludes (NULL) data of previous year

Comment: How do we know whether any particular Thursday is the one that we want? I.e. if today was `2014-03-07`, a Friday, do we want to obtain `2013-03-01` or `2013-03-08`? There are probably lots of edge cases, depending on what your definitions are, based around the starts and ends of months and possibly leap years may be a factor. Define what makes a particular week in the previous year "the same week".

Answer (score 5):

Basically you need to find difference in days between same dates in this and previous years, then understand "day difference" by mod 7, and sum it with date in previous year:

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME
SET @now = '2014-03-06'


SELECT CAST (DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @now) + (CAST (@now as INT) - CAST (DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @now) AS INT)) % 7 AS DATE)
```

Returns

```
2013-03-07
```

Comment: But that... boils down to [@Aishvarya Karthik's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22223241/297408) (which is *much* simpler and clearer).

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
DECLARE @now Date
SET @now = '2014-06-03'
SELECT DATEADD(week, -52, @now)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DateName(dw, DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE()))
```

gives `Wednesday`

```
SELECT DateName(dw, DateAdd(dd, 1, DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())))
```

gives `Thursday`

**edit:**

```
SELECT DateAdd(dd, 1, DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE()))
```

gives `'2013-03-07 17:30:16.590'`

you need to cast the date as per you requirement..

**update:**
change this part with,

```
Left JOIN #last_year ON #last_year.WeekNum =  DatePart(wk, GETDATE())
```

**in your case:**

```
Left JOIN #last_year ON DatePart(wk,  #last_year.[Date]) =  DatePart(wk, #current_year.[Date])
```

**update 2:**

```
Left JOIN #last_year ON (MONTH(#last_year.[Date])=MONTH(#current_year.[Date]) and Day(#last_year.[Date])=Day(#current_year.[Date]))
```

**Output:**

[image: Update output]

**or**

**output:**

```
Left JOIN #last_year ON (#last_year.WeekNum = #current_year.WeekNum and #last_year.[Day] = #current_year.[Day])
```

[image: output 2]
    
choose which ever is your required output.

Comment: I want to Get date value from this query: **SELECT DateName(dw, DateAdd(dd, 1, DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())))**

Comment: Buddy its fine as its giving me right date, but the thing is, I am displaying Data for both years of same day, despite of Dates , and I have Left join with source table and applied Conditions of equal Week# and WeekDay, But its giving me previous week record where i could not match the days.

Comment: May I post my Full Problem Statement? with Queries along and Screen Shot?

Comment: buddy i did as you said, but the issue is I have reposted my problem, by adding Join at below, It fetches 0 Zeros from Joined Table, Kindly execute query and see result

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2014-03-06'
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK,-52,@Date)
```

Retrun value :

> 2013-03-07